# Bootstrap - Justify divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to align my divs like on image below

[image]

my code looks like

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="#">restaurant</a>
        <a href="#">halls</a>
        <a href="#">menu</a>
        <a href="#">reservation</a>
        <a href="#">store</a>
        <a href="#">reviews</a>
        <a href="#">news</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The problem is I don't know how to do it with bootstrap. I tried to put `a` inside div with `col-md-2` class but its not aligned. Also I tried to set `float: left;` for first `a`, `float: right;` for last and set `text-align: center` for the rest of `a` but it's still not justified correct

Comment: what you get instead of this

Comment: If this is supposed to be a navigation you probably want to use navbars http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar instead of a simple container with columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it with bootstrap `nav`

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-justified">
      <li><a href="#"><%= t('navigation.restaurant') %></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><%= t('navigation.halls') %></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><%= t('navigation.menu') %></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><%= t('navigation.reservation') %></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><%= t('navigation.store') %></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><%= t('navigation.reviews') %></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><%= t('navigation.news') %></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li role="presentation"  class="active"><a href="#">restaurant</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">halls</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">menu</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">reservation</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">store</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">reviews</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">news</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you just have a to add few styles and a class that's it.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <a href="#">restaurant</a>
      <a href="#">halls</a>
      <a href="#">menu</a>
      <a href="#">reservation</a>
      <a href="#">store</a>
      <a href="#">reviews</a>
      <a href="#">news</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and styles

```
a {
  margin: 10px 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block
}

a:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0
}

a:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0
}
```

and here is the working fiddle..

**https://jsfiddle.net/Anuj_Kumar/45Lvf6r5/1/embedded/result/**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.container .row{
  text-align: center;
}
.container .row a{
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2fkauL04/)

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
.container
{
  background:black;
  padding:20px;
  float:left;
}
.row
{
  position:relative;

}
.col-md-12 a
{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;


 }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/a9z595L9/)

Answer (score -1):

This is the way to achieve this. It is called the Grid system in Bootstrap :

```
<div class=row>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <center><a href="#">restaurant</a></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <center><a href="#">halls</a></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <center><a href="#">menu</a></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <center><a href="#">reservation</a></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <center><a href="#">store</a></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <center><a href="#">reviews</a></center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <center><a href="#">news</a></center>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: `<center>` is not part of Bootstrap and, in fact, has been deprecated and so should not be used.